# Open multiple files using single file pointer

Tags: c, file, pointers

Can I open multiple file using a single file pointer in one loop?. I have an array of strings which contains 50 file names.It shows only one file name, then segmentation fault occur.  Please suggest.

```
int main()
{
  DIR *dir;
 struct dirent *pq;
 char f_name[40];
 const char *buffer[2000],*buffer1[2000];
 int count=0;
 if ((dir = opendir ("/home/student/storage")) != NULL)
  {
  /* print all the files and directories within directory */
  while ((pq = readdir (dir)) != NULL)
     {
       buffer[count]=pq->d_name;
       //printf("%s\n",pq->d_name);
       count++;
     }
  closedir (dir);
  }
 else
    {
  /* could not open directory */
    perror ("");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
 /*creating file name and removing unwanted names*/
 FILE *gh;
  char *s;
 int total=0,i;
   for(i=0;i<count;i++)
     {
      s = strstr(buffer[i],".txt");
      if (s !=NULL)
      {
       printf("%s\n",buffer[i]);
       buffer1[total]=buffer[i];//buffer1 contains all the required file name
       sprintf(f_name,"/home/student/storage/%s",buffer1[i]);
       //gh=fopen(f_name,"r");
       //data[total]=read(gh,data[i]);
       total++;
       //fclose(gh);
       }
 }
      printf("total=%d\n",total);
     return 0;
}

`
```

Comment: Show what you have tried, even if you think it's wrong.

Comment: you can open a single file using a file pointer. you can reuse the file pointer to open another file but after closing the previous opened file. so the steps will be like this 
1. open the file using a file pointer 
2. close the file using the file pointer
3. again reuse the file pointer to open another file.

Comment: @ rabi shaw i have done it.But it gives segmentation fault.

Comment: @  Michael Walz  can you suggest me alternative solution regarding this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can open multiple files using single file pointer, but before opening one file close the file using fclose() which was previously opened.

So in the loop first open the file and after doing operations close it before the loop ends.

Comment: collect the return values for fopen and read functions,
read() is having only two arguments in your code, but it should have three arguments.

Comment: @ Ash but still I get segmentation fault without read functions. Whenever fopen and fclose are present segmentation fault occur.

Comment: If the file you are trying to open is not there, the gh will be NULL, then fclose(NULL) will give you segmentation fault, so print the file name on console, and check whether they are present are not.

Comment: @  Ash yes file names are present in buffer1 array. Also total number of files present in that directory is also correct

Comment: check the return value for fopen and then do your operations and close the file if is is valid.
if(!gh)
fclose(gh);
Hope this will remove the segmentation fault

Comment: @ Ash fopen returns NULL value after it open 1st file. How to avoid this problem ?

Comment: so clearly the filepath is wrong, check whether you are getting the exact file path are not

Comment: @ Ash but it can process 1st file and process it. And buffer1 gives all the  required file names. f_name creates the path for each file.

Comment: fopen will set the errno if error occurs, so check the errno what was set

Comment: @ Ash thanks error number was 2  so I changed my code if(gh !=NULL){ data[total]=read(gh,data[i]);  fclose(gh);  }.  Now  segmentation fault does not occur but read function does not work.

Comment: @ Ash i changed my code and it worked. But i can handle up to 10 files. I have tried also with multiple file pointer and i saw this problem  here [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987093/open-multiple-files-for-reading-in-c). So  i think  i have less var . After processing my files terminal displays "KILLED". Thanks for your help.